# Kак сделать так, чтобы бнутренний SP всегда сделал commit, не смотря на то что главная процедура делает rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть три таблици

```
create table tbl1(id int identity, val nvarchar(50))
create table tbl2(id int identity, val nvarchar(50))
create table tbl3(id int identity, val nvarchar(50))
```

И есть две SP! `proc_out` и `proc_in`

```
create procedure proc_in
as
begin
    insert into tbl2(val)
    values ('test2')
end

create procedure proc_out
as
begin
   insert into tbl1(val)
   values('test1')

    exec proc_in

   insert into tbl3(val)
   values('test3')


    DECLARE @MessageText NVARCHAR(100);
    SET @MessageText = N'This is a raiserror %s';
    RAISERROR(@MessageText, 16, 1, N'MSG')
end
```

как мне написать `proc_out`, чтобы когда дал `raiserror, proc_in rollback` не сделал. я вызываю `proc_out` так

```
begin tran 
    declare @err int = 0
    exec @err = proc_out
if @ERR = 0 
    commit tran 
else 
    rollback tran
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlprogrammability/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Помните, что при наличии реферальных зависимостей фиксация субтранзакции теоретически может привести к нарушению логической целостности данных.

Comment: @Akina, а разве constraint позволит это сделать?? Мне кажется в этом случае должно выбросить исключение (exception).

Comment: @MaxU Это если он есть, constraint... порой зависимости таковы, что не укладываются во вменяемый constraint, или вообще контролируются на клиентском уровне.

Comment: @Akina, ну в таком случае с СУБД взятки гладки :)